# high latency when reading/writing using azure-kusto-spark

Tags: apache-spark, azure-data-explorer

I'm writing data to Kusto using azure-kusto-spark. This write has very small data. This spark-kusto connector uses batch streaming.

But I see this write has high latency running in like 8 minutes.

From the logs I see,  this high latency is in the staging ingestion part. I see that a temporary staging table is created, and data is ingested to it via multiple jobs. Only when staging ingestion is completed, data is finally merged and written to kusto table.

Can anyone give pointers why this small data is having so much of latency ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of your Kusto table ingestion policy as described here https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark/blob/master/docs/KustoSink.md#performance-considerations

You might want to modify the defautl ingestion policy and set the time to less than the default value which is 5 min. See this doc for reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/batchingpolicy#defaults-and-limits

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).